# Defining Spock mock behaviors

Tags: groovy, spock

I am writing my first Spock test and read the docs on [mocking interactions](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html), but am still not seeing the "forest through the trees" on a few items.

I have a class, `MyRealm`, that performs authentication for my app. It has two dependencies, `AuthService` and `ShiroAdapter`. The former I'd like to mock and the latter I want to leave as-is (if at all possible). This is because the `AuthService` actually makes a backend connection to LDAP, so I want to mock it. But the `ShiroAdapter` just defines several utility methods that convert my objects into Apache Shiro security objects (principals, permissions, etc.). So it can be left un-mocked (methinks).

```
class MyRealmSpec extends Specification {
    MyRealm realm

    def setup() {
        AuthService authService = Mock(AuthService)
        // configure 'authService' mock  <-- ?????

        ShiroAdapter shiroAdapter = new ShiroAdapter()

        realm = new MyRealm(authService: authService, 
            shiroAdapter: shiroAdapter)
    }

    def "authenticate throws ShiroException whenever auth fails"() {
        when:
        realm.authenticate('invalid_username', 'invalid_password')

        then:
        Throwable throwable = thrown()
        ShiroException.isAssignableFrom(throwable)
    }
}
```

I *believe* I'm very close, but am struggling to configure the mock to behave the way I want it to for the test. The Spock docs (linked above) only seem to document how to verify the *number of times* a mock method is called. I'm not interested in that here.

Here, `MyRealm#authenticate(String,String)` calls `AuthService#doAuth(String,String)` under the hood. So I need my mock `AuthService` instance to simply either return `false` (indicating failed auth) or to throw an `ServiceFaulException` if something unexpected happened.

**Any ideas how I can accomplish this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, an easy, short-hand way to check a thrown exception type is to put the `Exception` class in parenthesis. Ex:

```
def "authenticate throws ShiroException whenever auth fails"() {
    when:
    realm.authenticate('invalid_username', 'invalid_password')

    then:
    thrown(ShiroException)

}
```

You also need to mock the LDAP service call itself and simulate an exception or a failed login. The mock operations go in the then clause of your test.

```
def "authenticate throws ShiroException whenever auth fails"() {

    setup:
    String invalidUserName = 'invalid_username'
    String invalidPassword = 'invalid_password'

    when:
    realm.authenticate(invalidUserName, invalidPassword)

    then:
    1 * authService.doAuth(invalidUserName, invalidPassword) >> returnClosure  
    thrown(ShiroException)

    where:
    returnClosure << [{throw new ShiroException()}, { false }]
}
```

Note that you will need to have the arguments on the mock statements match or use wild card matching.

To match on any String you can use the underscore syntax:

```
1 * authService.doAuth(_, _) >> false
```

Comment: Thanks @Durandal (+1) - how do I achieve the "*OR*" logic in the `then` label? How would I change things to achieve "*AND*" logic there as well? Thanks again!

Comment: AND is implicit in `then` clauses, each mock invocation or conditional listed is checked in order provided; I was just putting OR in there to show an example of returning an exception vs returning a boolean. You could add a `where` clause to do both in the same test. I'll update to add that case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different behavior objects you might be interested in.

- Stub - You only define what gets returned

  ```
  MyObject obj = Stub{method >> null}
  ```
- Mocks - You define what gets returned and/or how many times a method is called

  ```
  MyObject obj = Mock {1..3 methodCall >> false}
  ```
- Spies - It creates your object but you can override specific methods as a mock (and your overrides can still make calls to the original code)

  ```
  MyObject obj = Spy {methodCall >> false}  
  obj.otherMethodCall()  // Calls code like normal
  obj.methodCall() // Returns false like we told it to
  ```

It sounds like you need a stub, but you could use a mock without any issue.  I mention spy, because it's a life-saver if your object ever is self dependent (in the future).

---

```
def "authenticate throws ShiroException whenever auth fails"() {
    given:
        AuthService authService = Stub(AuthService)
        authService.doAuth(_,_) >> expectedError
        MyRealm realm = new MyRealm(
            authService: authService, 
            shiroAdapter: new ShiroAdapter())
    when:
        realm.authenticate("just enough to get", "to the doAuth method")
    then:
        thrown(ShiroException)
    where:
        expectedError << [ShiroException, /*other exceptions this method has to test*/] 
}
```

The data/logic separation isn't needed, but it's a good approach for making tests more flexible and maintainable. Although in this case it's not really needed since you only have one exception to throw.

I would actually separate your failed authentication and exception-ed authentication tests. They're looking at fundamentally different behaviors and the test logic to test both situations is somewhat different. In the interest of maintainability/flexibility, it's in your interest to avoid testing too much (or too little) with each test.

```
def "authenticate throws ShiroException whenever auth fails"() {
    given:
        AuthService authService = Stub(AuthService)
        authService.doAuth(_,_) >> { args ->
           return args[0] == good && args[1] == good
        }
        MyRealm realm = new MyRealm(
            authService: authService, 
            shiroAdapter: new ShiroAdapter())
    expect:
        realm.authenticate(username, password) == expectedAuthentication

    where:
        userName | password | expectedAuthentication
         bad     |   good   |     false
         bad     |   bad    |     false
         good    |   good   |     true
}
```

Note on the above test, this tests...

1. The mock's computation for a return value (testing the test)
2. Any code that happens between calling authenticate and doAuth()

Hopefully that's what you intend. If there's nothing in .authenticate()'s logic that could break (it has complexity on par with a getter or setter method), this test is mostly a waste of time. The only way that logic could break is if something went wrong in the JVM (which is completely outside the responsibility of this test), or someone made a change sometime in the future (ok, even under the huge assumption that .authenticate() contains unbreakably basic logic the test has some value).  My rambling off-topic point (terribly sorry); make sure to keep the what & why of your tests in mind.  It will help you prioritize test cases and while working out the best ways to organize/separate test logic.

Comment: Can you able post the reference?